# error when using cgi with clisp

Tags: cgi, common-lisp, clisp

I have written a hello world cgi program that looks like this:
(well just a 'hello' program really)

```
#! /usr/bin/env clisp

(format t "Content-type: text/html~C~C" #\linefeed #\linefeed)
(format t "<h1>hello</h1>")
```

When I run it on the command line, there are no errors:

```
$ ./cgi-bin/hello.lisp 
Content-type: text/html

<h1>hello</h1>
```

However, when I serve it through either ubuntu's default apache or `python3 -m http.server --cgi`, although I get the expected result in the browser, I get the following in the error log:

```
*** - UNIX error 14 (EFAULT): Bad address

[/build/buildd/clisp-2.49/src/eval.d:573] reset() found no driver frame (sp=0x7ffff98ef0d0-0x7ffff98ea570)
```

Does anybody know what that is?

----EDIT----

Maybe given the comments, a better question is... does anybody know what what I would have to do to reproduce the same error without cgi?  I have tried copying the environment that the server passes in, and I have tried piping into other programs.

(I guess this is more of a cgi question than a clisp question)

Comment: Looks similar to this http://clisp-list.narkive.com/J499cUN5/unix-error-14-efault

Comment: [CLISP FAQ: How do I report bugs?](https://clisp.sourceforge.io/impnotes/faq.html#faq-bugs)

Comment: oh thanks - I didn't realise it was a bug.  I just thought I was doing something wrong.

Comment: CLISP crash is nearly always a bug.